# how am I supposed to understand this code? Node.js

Tags: node.js

I've been currently studying on MEAN stack to be an web programmer, I was stuck in this code, which I couldn't even guess at all. Can someone please tell me what this means and where this is from?

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var _url;

  ....

  if(_url = /^\/employees$/i.exec(req.url)){
    res.writeHead(200);
    return res.end('employee list');
  }else if(_url = /^\/employees\/(\d+)$/i.exec(req.url)){
    res.writeHead(200);
    return res.end('a single employee');
  }else{
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('static file maybe');
  }
});
```

So, what I want to know is these parts below:

- _url = /^/employees$/i.exec(req.url)
- _url = /^/employees/(\d+)$/i.exec(req.url)

Comment: These are regular expressions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `/^\/employees$/i` is a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that is checking if the request url includes the string `/employees` without anything after

if a match was found _url will be a string (a truthy value), otherwise it will be null (a falsy value)

`_url = /^/employees/(\d+)$/i.exec(req.url)` is looking for `/employees/NUMBER`

`^` means beginning of string

`\/` is escaping `/`

`employees` is a literal string

`\d` means any digit

`$` means end of string

`i` means not case sensitive (both `EmPlOyeeS` and `employees` will match the same)

Answer (score 0):

`^\/employees$`

```
^ - Begins with
\/ - Escaped '/'. (i.e. begins with '/')
employees - contains employees.
$ - ends with (i.e. finally, it'll only match '/employees')
```

`^\/employees\/(\d+)$`

Here, the (\d+) is a group where:

```
\d - matches digits (0-9)

+ - one or more previous token (i.e. matches 012345 or 1234 or 23, etc. but not blank or string).
```